# ¿Dónde me equivoco?

Tags: python, imprimir

Escribe código que lea el fichero file1.txt  y que para cada línea del fichero, meta las palabras en una lista e imprima dicha lista.Se imprimirán tantas listas como líneas en el fichero.

```
 with open("file11.txt", "w") as eje42:
   j = input("introduzca una lista de palabra: ")
   i = []
   i = j.replace(" ","").split(",")
   for linea in i:
     eje42.write(linea)
 with open("file11.txt", "r") as eje42:
   print(eje42.read())
```

Pero al parecer lo estoy haciendo mal, ya que tiene estos requisitos

- Cuando se habla de palabras, se refiere a las unidades de texto
  separadas por espacios

  Tener en cuenta que la función readlines() lee caracteres utf-8

Answer (score 1):

```
    with open("file11.txt", "w") as eje42:
        # Leo las palabras
        palabras = input("introduzca una lista de palabras separadas por ',': ")
        # Las separo por el caracter solicitado y creo un arreglo
        lista_de_palabras = palabras.split(",")

        # Recorro el arreglo y escribo cada palabra agregandole el caracter de salto de línea
        for palabra in lista_de_palabras:
            eje42.write(palabra + "\n")
    with open("file11.txt", "r") as eje42:
        #Leo el archivo nuevamente
        print(eje42.read())

    eje42.close()

"""
Al hacer esto 
i = j.replace(" ","").split(",")
Primero estás cambiando los espacios por nada, entonces queda todo junto, y al hacer el split por el caracter "," no hay nada para separar.
"""
```